# How to add and subtract numbers in the DOM with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, math

I am trying to figure out how to keep track of multiple Add and Remove counters with a Javascript Object and to update the DOM with the data in the object.

My HTML:

```
<div id="first-counter-box">
    <div id="first-number">0</div>
    <div id="first-add" onclick="add(first)"></div>
    <div id="first-minus" onclick="minus(first)"></div>
</div>

<div id="second-counter-box">
    <div id="second-number">0</div>
    <div id="second-add" onclick="add(second)"></div>
    <div id="second-minus" onclick="minus(second)"></div>
</div>
```

My Javascript:

```
var dataObject = {
    firstCounter = 0;
    secondCounter = 0;
}

function add(counterId) {
    if (counterId==first) {
      dataObject.firstCounter++;
      var firstNumber = document.getElementbyID("first-number");
      firstNumber.innerHTML(dataObject.firstCounter);
    }
    else (counterId==second) {
        dataObject.secondCounter++;
        var secondNumber = document.getElementbyID("second-number");
        secondNumber.innerHTML(dataObject.secondCounter);
    }

}

function remove(counterId) {
    if (counterId==first) {
        dataObject.firstCounter--;
        var firstNumber = document.getElementbyID("first-number");
        firstNumber.innerHTML(dataObject.firstCounter);
    }
    else (counterId==second) {
        dataObject.secondCounter--;
        var secondNumber = document.getElementbyID("second-number");
        secondNumber.innerHTML(dataObject.secondCounter);
    }
}
```

My aim is to update the data within the dataObject with the add() and remove() functions, and to update the DOM with updated information.

I'm sure there is a better way to go about this than my gross javascript does it. Thank you!

Comment: Right off the bat your object definition is completely wrong... Then there's the incorrect capitalisation of `getElementById`... Then the fact that `innerHTML` is a property, not a method. And you never define `first` and `second` (should they be strings?) All in all, is it any mystery it doesn't work?

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on Kolink's comment, but to be more productive, here is some real help:

```
<div id="first-counter-box">
    <div id="first-number">0</div>
    <div id="first-add" onclick="add('first')"></div> <-- first is a string -->
    <div id="first-minus" onclick="minus('first')"></div> <-- first is a string -->
</div>

<div id="second-counter-box">
    <div id="second-number">0</div>
    <div id="second-add" onclick="add('second')"></div> <-- second is a string -->
    <div id="second-minus" onclick="minus('second')"></div> <-- second is a string -->
</div>
```

and the js:

```
var dataObject = { // correct object instantiation
    firstCounter: 0,
    secondCounter: 0
}

function add(counterId) {
    if (counterId=='first') { // first is a string
      dataObject.firstCounter++;
      var firstNumber = document.getElementById("first-number"); // correct capitalization
      firstNumber.innerHTML = dataObject.firstCounter; // property, not method
    }
    else (counterId=='second') { // second is a string
        dataObject.secondCounter++;
        var secondNumber = document.getElementById("second-number"); // correct capitalization
        secondNumber.innerHTML = dataObject.secondCounter; // property, not method
    }

}

function remove(counterId) {
    if (counterId=='first') { // first is a string
        dataObject.firstCounter--;
        var firstNumber = document.getElementById("first-number"); // correct capitalization
        firstNumber.innerHTML = dataObject.firstCounter; // property, not method
    }
    else (counterId=='second') { // second is a string
        dataObject.secondCounter--;
        var secondNumber = document.getElementById("second-number"); // correct capitalization
        secondNumber.innerHTML = dataObject.secondCounter; // property, not method
    }
}
```

---

Here is a re-write to be more efficient:

```
var dataObject = { // keys match the counters
    'first': 0,
    'second': 0
};

var divRefs = {
    'first': document.getElementById("first-number"),
    'second': document.getElementById("second-number")
};

function add(counterId) {
    dataObject[counterId]++;
    divRefs[counterId].innerHTML = dataObject[counterId];
}

function remove(counterId) {
    dataObject[counterId]--;
    divRefs[counterId].innerHTML = dataObject[counterId];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried the code above and it successfully updates the dataObject, however for some reason, it was not updating the DOM via innerHTML...

Comment: getElementById is still capitalized wrong. The `b` needs to be capitalized `B`.

Comment: That was it exactly. Thank you all!